# Same kernels for homomorphisms of free modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $f: R^n \rightarrow R^m$ be an isomorphism of free $R$-modules ($R$ commutative with unity) and $\pi_1: R^n \rightarrow R^n/\mathfrak m^n$, $\pi_2: R^m \rightarrow R^m/\mathfrak m^m$ the canonical projections where $\mathfrak m$ is an arbitrary maximal ideal in $R$.

How to see $\ker \pi_1 = \ker \pi_2 \circ f$?

If $x=(x_1, ..., x_n) \in \ker \pi_1$ then $x_i \in\mathfrak m$ for all $i$.

Since $f$ is an isomorphism we can "identify" $R^n$ with $R^m$, thus "$(\pi_2 \circ f) (x) = \pi_2 (x) = 0$". Similarly the other inclusion can be "shown". But I do not see how to prove the equation without using this heuristic argument (for example by doing it concretely elementwise).

**context**: proof of $R^n \cong R^m \Rightarrow m=n$ via reduction to fields.

Comment: You're right to be suspicious of the "identify" argument, since it's not immediately obvious the isomorphism should identify the submodule $\mathfrak{m}^n$ with the submodule $\mathfrak{m}^m$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submodule $\mathfrak{m}^n$ is exactly the same as
$$
\mathfrak{m}R^n=\{a_1x_1+\dots+a_kx_k: a_i\in\mathfrak{m}, x_i\in R^n\}
$$
Indeed, if $x\in\mathfrak{m}R^n$, then $x\in\mathfrak{m}^n$, by looking at the components. If $x=(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in\mathfrak{m}^n$, then
$$
x=a_1(1,0,\dots,0)+\dots+a_n(0,\dots,0,1)\in\mathfrak{m}R^n
$$

Since $f$ is an isomorphism, it maps $\mathfrak{m}R^n$ onto $\mathfrak{m}R^m$.

This can be seen more easily with a homomorphism $f\colon M\to N$; if $x\in M$ and $a\in\mathfrak{m}$, then $f(ax)=af(x)\in\mathfrak{m}N$.

Comment: This helped a lot. Is it right that if $f$ were a monomorphism we could not conclude $n \leq m$ (while when $f$ is an epimorphism we can conclude $ n \geq m$)?

Comment: @CHwC I think so.